# filter undefined in my JavaScript in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem that i use the filter in my javascript code and its work but the problem that shows in error in console.
i used this code for html:

```
 <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" ng-model="ctrl.inputAge" />
        100</p>
        <span>current min age: {{ ctrl.inputAge }}</span>
       <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in ctrl.people | ageFilter:ctrl.inputAge ">{{ person.name }} ({{ person.age }})</li>
```

so this is my filter code :

```
  var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.inputAge = 25;

.filter('ageFilter', function() {
    return function(input, minAge) {
      return input.filter(function (person) {
          return person.age >= +minAge;
      });
    }
  });
```

so i found this error in my console :

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

Comment: This code is not enough to understand the problem can you please post full code.

Comment: sorry u can now check the error

Answer (score 0):

Are you "attaching" the `filter` to an existing module? a filter defined with `.filter` (also when using `.controller`, `.factory`, `.service` etc.) must exist in a scope defined by a module. You have a working example below.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.myPersons = [{
    name: "Joe",
    age: 30
  }, {
    name: "Mary",
    age: 36
  }, {
    name: "George",
    age: 45
  }];
});

app.filter('ageFilter', function() {
  return function(items, threshold) {
    return items.filter(i => i.age > threshold);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{ testString }}
  
  <div ng-repeat="x in myPersons | ageFilter:35">
    {{ x.name }} - {{ x.age }} 
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I used `app.filter`, where `app` was previously defined. You can have separate files for your filters as it is recommended to have separate files for your controllers, services etc.

Cheers!